# Visual Basic Counter Loop In Excel

Tags: java, vba, loops

I need to code a simple counter in visual basic. I'm doing a "how many licks to the center of a tootsie pop counter". A dialog box will open asking if they've reached the center. If answered no, it will loop around and ask again.

If answered yes, it will end the program and count how many loops there were. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you so much

I have the java code if that helps:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Counter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        int counter = 0;
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Are you are the center? ");
        String answer = input.readLine();
        while(answer.equals("no")) { 
            System.out.print("Are you are the center? ");
            counter++; 
            answer = input.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("It took " + ++counter + " licks.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the java code if that helps


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Counter {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
int counter = 0;
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Are you are the center? ");

String answer = input.readLine();
while(answer.equals("no")) {
System.out.print("Are you are the center? ");
counter++;
answer = input.readLine();
}
System.out.println("It took " + ++counter + " licks.");
}
}

Comment: Are you trying to write a program in Visual Basic that does the same thing as that Java code? What do you have so far? Is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

Though Jon Lin asked what youre asking this for I am dying to reply to this post. I'm a new user too, and this is the first question that is easy enough for me to answer. So I hope I'm not crossing the line here, but here goes my answer, that worked for me:

```
Sub HowManyClicks()

Dim numberOfClicks As Integer
Dim title As String
Dim question As String
Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

title = "How many (c)licks"
question = "Are you at the center?"

answer = vbNo

Do

 answer = MsgBox(question, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, title)
 numberOfClicks = numberOfClicks + 1

Loop While answer = vbNo

MsgBox "it took" & Str(numberOfClicks) & " (c)licks", , title

End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to be using recursion to implement the loop. This is probably fine for this simple application, but in a real live program such recursion can be a real performance drain. Consider changing your answer to use a while loop (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx)

Comment: thanks, I didnt realise that recursion is generally less efficient. Changed it!

Comment: The `&` operator is dedicated to string concatenation, whereas `+` does a lot of different things. Definite +1 for declaring variables, typing them, and explicit conversion of `arg` to string, -1 for `arg` isn't a meaningful variable name in the context, and some variables names have uppercase 1st letter...